# Need a simple comparison with time() to execute things

Tags: c++, time

I'm using an Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266 controller for a wordclock, which is a birthday present and should also be a marriage proposal.

Last time I programmed was years ago in school, so I'm rather noobish to that.
My plan is to make a simple condition if the desired time is reached (its only once), then light up some LEDs (marry me and her name) in heartform.
To not be overwritten a minute later i think an infinite while loop would be best. Push Reset and the clock gets time again over NTP.

So I searched for correct unix timestamp and tried things like

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    while (time()==1461337750)
or
    time_t t;
    t = time(NULL);  //oder time(&t);
    if (t==1461335820)
    }
```

but it didn't show anything.
I don't know what is the right way and need help, please! I searched the Inet for hours but couldn't find a similar task or I thought it wasn't.

Comment: `==` is not the best idea to compare times if you are interested in one particular point in time. Chances that the condition is evaluated just at the right time is rather small.

Comment: To add to @tobi303's comment, perhaps use `>=` instead of `==`? Then it would just stay on after that time.

Comment: Or `while ( time() > 1461337750  &&  time() < 1461339000 ) { // ... do something...` to set an intervall...

Comment: (Almost) Nothing happens at _exactly_ the same time but nice idea and good luck :)

Comment: If you don't want to drain the battery, it would be a good idea to put the CPU to sleep somewhere here : `while( time(NULL)<1461335820 ) sleep(1);` *then* light up the LEDs. Oh, and good luck ;-)

Comment: @FirstStep true, but we also dont have clocks that can measure time **exact**, the best ones I know count nanoseconds, which raises the probability of two events happening "at the same time" from zero to something

Comment: I think what @bob suggested is the best. `While (time within a range)`

Comment: That sounds plausible. I will try this out later (have to go now) and tell you the result, many thanks! :-) Edit: Couldn't do anything yesterday, suddenly got a gastrointestinal illnesses. Tested it with `while ( time(NULL) > 1461395760 && time(NULL) < 1461395940 )
 {
  time_t timer;
  timer = time(NULL);
  printf("Sekunden seit 1. Januar 1970 : %ld", timer);
 }` , now I try it with the LEDs.

Comment: While in Eclipse it works flawlessly, in Arduino IDE there are so many errors. Couldn't do this, so I finally get it to run with `while (month()==4 && day()==23 && hour()==14 && minute()<10)`, but sadly it had no effect. Maybe I have to find the right spot to place it in...